# running an SQL query and ordering by number of rows from another table

Tags: php, sql, join

Basically,

I have two tables, one with Some posts on and another for comments, what I am trying to do is create a page with the **most popular posts**, I will render popular posts depending on how many comments it has.

Here's the query I have so far

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.content_id ORDER BY count('comments.id') LIMIT 10");
```

But the count() is messing it up, could  anyone help me? THANKS!

Comment: Is an error being returned, or is it just not working?

Comment: I fixed it myself, sorry, I needed to add a GROUP BY function in the query

Comment: Isn't your ORDER BY backwards? It will give you the *least* popular posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an aggregate function, such as `COUNT(*)`, you should include a `GROUP BY` clause:

Also, since you want to return posts with the most comments, you'll want to sort by the count in descending order (highest to lowest).

```
SELECT 
    posts.id, 
    COUNT(comments.content_id) as post_comments 
FROM 
    posts 
    LEFT JOIN comments 
        ON posts.id = comments.content_id 
GROUP BY posts.id
ORDER BY post_comments DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotations around comments.id :) I've also added the group by that I believe is missing.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.content_id GROUP BY posts.id ORDER BY count(comments.id) LIMIT 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the count statement and add a group by:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.content_id 
GROUP BY comments.content_id
ORDER BY count(comments.content_id) 
LIMIT 10
```